# Acessar atributos de vários relacionamentos diferentes num CRUD Eloquent Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Galera eu tenho uma estrutura igual a desse modelo **`(Modelo apenas ilustrativo)`** e quero saber como posso acessar os dados de todo o relacionamento para fazer um `insert/update` nessas tabelas com os dados recebidos de um form, sendo que eu consigo dar um `select` com `LEFT JOIN` em todas essas tabelas usando uma `query` com `DB::raw`, mas quero saber como fazer isso somente com os métodos do eloquent. **Desde processo à arquivo**:

[image: Modelo do Banco de Dados]

Onde como podem ver ***um*** `Processo` tem apenas ***uma*** `solicitacao` e vice versa, ***uma*** `solicitacao` pode ter ***N*** boxes e um box podem estar em ***N*** `solicitacoes`, sendo que ***um*** `box` pode ter ***N*** `arquivos`.

Meu Model Processo estaria assim:

```
public function processo_solicitacao (){
 return $this->belongTo(Solicitacao::class, 'id_solicitacao', 'solicitacao_id');
}
```

Meu Model solicitacao assim:

```
public function processo (){
 return $this->hasOne(Processo::class);
}
```

Meu Model box assim:

```
public function solicitacoes (){
 return $this->belongsToMany(Processo::class);
}
public function arquivos(){
 return $this->hasMany(Arquivo::class);
}
```

Meu Model arquivo assim:

```
public function solicitacoes (){
 return $this->belongsTo(Box::class, 'box_id', 'id_box');
}
```

Desde já agradeço qualquer ajuda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contando que seus relacionamentos estejam corretos, você pode chamar o método estatico `create` de cada model, em uma ordem que você tenha todos os dados necessários.

Exemplo:

```
$solicitacao = Solicitacao::create([ 'info1' => 'valor1' ... ]);
$box = Box::create([ 'info1' => 'valor1' ...]);
$box->associate($solicitacao); // ou
$box->associate($solicitacao->id);
$box->save();
```

E assim por diante...

Comment: `associate()` em uma relação N:N ?   
Não seria `$solicitacao->attach($box);`   
`$box->associate($arquivo);` ?? fico perdido nos relacionamentos do laravel =(

Comment: Não, o associate() é para uma relação 1:N ou 1:1.
N:N você tem outros métodos, como attach([ id1, id2...]), etc...
Foi apenas um exemplo, não me atentei que esse era um N:N. Perdão pelo meu exemplo.

Comment: Tranquilo, entendi então, eu tenho que preencher todas as tabelas individualmente e depois sair relacionando =)

Comment: Exato, lembre-se que o método ``Model::create`` e ``Model::update`` executam um save, se na sua tabela os id's estiverem ``not null``, vai lançar uma exceção.
Se for o caso de mante-los not null, recomendo dar um ```$model = new Model; $model->attribute = $value; .... $model->attach() // ou $model->associate()```.